# only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, urlencode

I have converted 4,000 lines of code from VB.net to c#... I am totally tripped up on this one problem.   This keeps giving me the error that "Only assignment, call increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Any help on what the error is here?  It also is throwing an error that a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.

```
protected static string AssembleArgumentString(Dictionary<string, string> @params,   bool urlEncode)
{
   if (urlEncode) {
     return string.Join("&", (from kv in @params where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value)kv.Key + "=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kv.Value)).ToArray);
   } 
   else {
     return string.Join("&", (from kv in @params where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value)kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value).ToArray);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `select` clause in your LINQ query.  For example:

```
return string.Join("&", (from kv in @params where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value) select kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value).ToArray());
```

Also, don't forget the `()` at the end of the `ToArray` method call.  You actually don't even need the `ToArray()` because `String.Join()` can take an `IEnumerable` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected static string AssembleArgumentString(Dictionary<string, string> @params,   bool urlEncode)
{
    if (urlEncode)
    {
        return string.Join("&", (from kv in @params where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value)
                                 select kv.Key + "=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kv.Value)));

    }
    else
    {
        return string.Join("&", (from kv in @params where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value)
                                 select kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value));
    } 
}
```